# how to make the text centerlized in the box in CSS? Mine didn't work

Tags: html, css

Tried to make the text, actually a link, inside "content_a" centrelized. But it's always on the right side. Could someone help to fix it? Appreciate it!

here is the code for HTML

```css
.container{
 padding: 1em;
 margin: 0.5em;
 display: inline-block;
}
.container .box_a{
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}
.content_a{
 position: absolute;
 height: calc(100%-50px);
 top: 50px;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 font-size: 20px;
 transition: 0.5s;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 10;
}

.box_a:hover .content_a{
 opacity: 1; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box_a" id="env">
  <div class="icon" >
      <i class="fa fa-envelope e" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="content_a">
      <a href="xxx@gmail.com"><p>xxx@gmail.com</p></a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: you need space here `calc(100%-50px)` --> `calc(100% - 50px)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your issue here is that you have position absolute set, for some reason.

Your `.content a` should be really simple. Maybe a width on there, but everything else needs to be removed.

You could also do this in flex.

```
.container .box_a{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **.content_a** class needs a `left: 0` attribute. At the moment it´s already centered but the whole `<a>` tag is simply not in the right spot.